# log out is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys i am trying to use logout code in my codigniter so due to some reason its not working properly.

Here is my logout code:

```
 public function Logout() {
    $this->Login_model->saveLogout();
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('Login');
}
```

Here is my model code:

```
    public function saveLogout() {
    $recordId=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
     $ipaddress = $this->input->ip_address();
    $dataLog = array(
        'userid' => $recordId,
        'entertime' => time(),
        'ip' => $ipaddress,
        'log_operation' => 'Logout'
    );
    $dataUser = array(
        'previous_visit' => time(),
        'lastip' => $ipaddress
    );
    $this->db->insert('log_table', $dataLog);
    $this->db->set($dataUser); //value that used to update column  
    $this->db->where('id', $recordId); //which row want to upgrade  
    $this->db->update('users');  //table name
}
```

When i clicked on logout it is showing this below error

```
    Column 'userid' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `log_table` (`userid`, `entertime`, `ip`, `log_operation`) VALUES (NULL, 1534252667, '::1', 'Logout')
```

Can anyone help me what is the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're confusing `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. You probably want to do one or the other, not both.

Comment: what it mean?i didn't understand what you are saying

Comment: You can `INSERT` a new row into the table, or you can `UPDATE` an existing row with new values. I'm not terribly familiar with CodeIgniter but you appear to be doing both: `$this->db->insert()` and then `$this->db->update()`

Comment: OK I was confused by your code at first, I think you *are* trying to do both an insert and an update, is this correct? One insert to log the act, and one to update to the user record?

Comment: yes exactly alex

Comment: Does the update work correctly?

Comment: no its not updating alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `$this->session->sess_destroy();` without any condition check write after other, it will destroy the session before execute other. ***Same like [headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)***

Do like this

**In Controller**

```
public function Logout() {
    $return = $this->Login_model->saveLogout(); # alter

    if(!$return)
    {
        echo "went wong"; die;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Login');
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function saveLogout() {

    # your model code

    return true; # add this
}
```

Comment: can you please  check this question and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924399/get-td-values-display-as-static-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment90798509_51924399

Comment: i am trying from past few days i didn't get any idea of how to do can you please help me

Comment: i have one doubt may i ask